# How to calculate PP variance in SAP?

Tags: sap

I am trying to figure out how to determine the PP tolerance is exceeded in SAP and how PP variance is calculated to compare to the PP variance. As an example, if I set the upper/lower absolute PP variance as 50 and upper/lower percentage as 10%

[image: see screenshot here]

Then if I created a PO of 1000 units of a material for $1.00 each. I received 100 units. In the invoice creation, I invoiced 120 units of the material for a total of $100 (see screenshot below). In this case, how is the absolute and percentage PP variance be determined (e.g. would I be using the PO amount of $100 or the invoice amount of $100?) and what is the formula to determine that?

[image: see screenshot here]